# Avoiding nvcc compilation when using Cudafy

Tags: c#, cudafy.net

I'm using Cudafy and would like my users to be able to use CUDA without installing the CUDA SDK, but they can use the Cudafy DLL. To avoid nvcc compilation done automatically in `CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(types)`, I'm using the following approach:

```
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string modulePath = Path.Combine(directory, myType.Name + ".cdfy");
CudafyModule km = CudafyModule.TryDeserialize(modulePath);
if (ReferenceEquals(km, null) || !km.TryVerifyChecksums())
{
    km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(types);
    km.Serialize(modulePath);
}
GPU.LoadModule(km);
```

Where `types` is an array of `System.Type`s.

The problem is in the third line, `TryDeserialize` always returns `null`. I have checked that the file exists and the `modulePath` is correct and the file exists. Can someone please shed some light on the matter?

I'm ready to change my approach if it doesn't mean re-writing my Cudafy modules.

Comment: I've just run into the same problem but your code seems to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is my function (which is partially based on your code btw):

```
public static void LoadTypeModule(GPGPU gpu, Type typeToCudafy)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading module "+typeToCudafy.Name);

    string appFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string typeModulePath = Path.Combine(appFolder, typeToCudafy.Name + ".cdfy");

    CudafyModule cudaModule = CudafyModule.TryDeserialize(typeModulePath);
    if (cudaModule == null || !cudaModule.TryVerifyChecksums())
    {
        // if failed to open module:
        // translate the type's code to cuda code
        cudaModule = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(typeToCudafy);
        cudaModule.Serialize(); // save to file
    }
    // load module to cuda memory, don't unload previous modules
    gpu.LoadModule(cudaModule, false);
}
```

Now calling the function:

```
MyClassWithCudaKernels classModule = new MyClassWithCudaKernels();
LoadTypeModule(gpu, classModule.GetType());
```